# display particular image based on custom field data

Tags: php, image

I want to pull one of 5 images into a post based on the data within a custom field.

For example:
if the custom field is 1 then image A is displayed.
if the custom field is 2 then image B is displayed.
if the custom field is 3 then image C is displayed.
if the custom field is 4 then image D is displayed.

Thanks

Comment: I have not one clue what you are trying to get. Maybe show use what you got or what doesn't work

Comment: Well simply want to use PHP on Wordpress to pull in an image. A different image would be displayed depending on the custom field data.

I realise I shouldn't be using the below for example:

<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ecpt_fieldtwo', true ); ?>

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do this, name the images you like to corrospond with the input like a input of 1 would load 1.jpg

Btw this code below is just an example. You need to verify stuff to whether it is a image file. Else people would be able to load other stuff you might not like to be loaded.

```
<?php
echo '<img src="image_folder/'+ $customfieldvalue +'.jpg" />';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.

I can't seem to get it working...

custom field is ecpt_shrating and the options are hell > heavenly. Using the below but it's outputting '00000

<?php
echo '<img src="/'+ $hell +'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Address.gif" />';
?>
<?php
echo '<img src="/'+ $poor +'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Address.gif" />';
?>
<?php
echo '<img src="/'+ $nice +'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Address.gif" />';
?>
<?php
echo '<img src="/'+ $angelic +'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Address.gif" />';
?>
<?php
echo '<img src="/'+ $heavenly +'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Address.gif" />';
?>

Comment: Thanks so I got to this then:

Comment: Thank you - I just cannot work this out to save my life - any help would be hugely appreciated...I got someway through but possibly in the wrong direction :-(